# Object.keys(obj) returning items not in obj

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to return all the keys of my obj to create a header row in Google Apps Script. This is what is returned when I console.log(obj):

`{tagId=270, accountId=XXXXX, monitoringMetadata={type=map}, firingTriggerId=[18], type=sp, containerId=XXXXX, workspaceId=XXXXX, name=GADR - Product Detail View - Product Detail Page, tagManagerUrl=https://tagmanager.google.com/#/container/accounts/XXX/containers/XXX/workspaces/XXX/tags/270?apiLink=tag, parameter=[{value={{CJ - GADR SKU - Product Detail Page}}, type=template, key=eventItems}, {type=template, key=eventValue, value={{DLV - Product Price - Product Detail Pages}}}, {value=true, key=enableDynamicRemarketing, type=boolean}, {type=list, key=customParams, list=[{map=[{type=template, key=key, value=product_name}, {key=value, type=template, value={{DLV - Product Name - Product Detail Pages}}}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{value=product_price, type=template, key=key}, {key=value, type=template, value={{DLV - Product Price - Product Detail Pages}}}]}, {map=[{type=template, key=key, value=product_id}, {value={{DLV - Product ID - Product Detail Pages}}, type=template, key=value}], type=map}, {map=[{value=product_category, type=template, key=key}, {value={{DLV - Product Category - Product Detail Pages}}, key=value, type=template}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{value=user_id, key=key, type=template}, {value={{DLV - User ID - All Pages}}, type=template, key=value}]}, {map=[{value=user_status, type=template, key=key}, {type=template, value={{DLV - User Status - All Pages}}, key=value}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{value=page_type, type=template, key=key}, {key=value, value={{DLV - Page Type - All Pages}}, type=template}]}, {map=[{type=template, value=user_purchase_count, key=key}, {key=value, type=template, value={{DLV - User Purchase Count - All Pages}}}], type=map}, {type=map, map=[{value=user_lifetime_value, type=template, key=key}, {key=value, value={{DLV - User Lifetime Value - All Pages}}, type=template}]}]}, {type=template, value=view_item, key=eventName}, {type=template, value={{CST - Google Ads ID - All Pages}}, key=conversionId}, {type=template, value=USER_SPECIFIED, key=customParamsFormat}, {key=rdp, value=false, type=boolean}], tagFiringOption=oncePerEvent, path=accounts/XXX/containers/XXXX/workspaces/XXXX/tags/270, fingerprint=1608071670124}`

And this is what is outputted when I `console.log(Object.keys(obj));`

`[setMonitoringMetadataTagNameKey, setName, setTagFiringOption, setNotes, getMonitoringMetadata, tagId, firingTriggerId, getSetupTag, getFiringTriggerId, getName, name, getTagFiringOption, getParentFolderId, setWorkspaceId, containerId, getFingerprint, getTagManagerUrl, parameter, getBlockingTriggerId, setLiveOnly, setFingerprint, setTagManagerUrl, getContainerId, setScheduleEndMs, setTagId, getPaused, path, setContainerId, getLiveOnly, setFiringTriggerId, getBlockingRuleId, getFiringRuleId, getTagId, setTeardownTag, getTeardownTag, setFiringRuleId, getType, getPriority, accountId, setPaused, monitoringMetadata, setScheduleStartMs, getNotes, setParameter, toString, setParentFolderId, getPath, setSetupTag, fingerprint, setAccountId, getAccountId, workspaceId, setBlockingTriggerId, type, tagFiringOption, tagManagerUrl, getMonitoringMetadataTagNameKey, setPriority, setType, getScheduleEndMs, setBlockingRuleId, setPath, getParameter, getWorkspaceId, getScheduleStartMs, setMonitoringMetadata]`

I'm getting all of these extra keys that start with set and get that don't exists in the obj and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Where is your [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those keys exists in object and that's why they're shown, when those keys are retrieved using `Object.keys()`. `console.log()` in Apps Script attempts to stringify the object(albeit in a weird/non-standard fashion due to custom implementation in apps script) and [stringify excludes functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) and therefore they're are not shown when the script directly logs using `console.log()`.

You can iterate over the object and filter those functions out:

```
const keysWithoutFunctions = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => typeof obj[key] !== 'function')
```

Comment: That did it! It's weird because those function keys don't exist in the Google Tag Manager documentation. Any way to see what the object actually contains, including all functions?

Comment: @George Didn't you already see it? Using `Object.keys()`? Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Comment: I can see the keys, but not the data associated with those keys. Those keys don't exist in the GTM documentation, so I don't know what they are or why they're there.

Comment: @George They're functions. You can access the method using `object[key]`, but  you still won't be able to see function's source code(You can execute the function though: `object[key](argument)`).  Judging by their names, they're "getters and setters".